# OpenLDAP 2.4+ : Shall I use OnLine Configuration and convert kerberos.schema or not?

Tags: kerberos, openldap

I am currently trying to install on a cluster a Kerberos + LDAP solution.

The question is, in the slapd.conf, if I put :

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/kerberos.schema
```

and in the index :

```
index           krbPrincipalName eq,pres,sub
```

Then do I really need to make a runtime conversion for the cn=config ? Or it is ok not to do it and just let the include in the slapd.conf ? All the tutorial I saw about kerberos + LDAP were with LDAP =< 2.3 and I have trouble using :

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f  /tmp/krb5_ldif/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={0}kerberos.ldif
```

The mechanism EXTERNAL is not working like in this outdated post:

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.11/doc/admin/advanced/ldapbackend.html#ldap-be-ubuntu
http://labs.opinsys.com/blog/2010/02/01/setting-up-openldap-on-ubuntu-10-04-alpha-2-lucid-part-3/

and here I don't see it: (krb5-1.6 is the one I use).

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.6/krb5-1.6.2/doc/krb5-admin.html#Configuring-Kerberos-with-OpenLDAP-back_002dend

Thanks for your advices :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hopelessly confused.

1. If you're using online configuration you need to use the cn=config database rather than slapd.conf. This has nothing to do with (2) or (3). Which you use is up to you. Neither of them is mandatory. *That's why they're both provided.* Surely this is obvious?
2. If you're using the Kerberos schema you need to load it into whatever configuration system you're using: see (1). This has nothing to do with (3).
3. The EXTERNAL SASL authentication mechanism has nothing to do with either (1) or (2).

Comment: Well my question is, should I use Online configuration ? They don't seem to use it in:
http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.6/krb5-1.6.2/doc/krb5-admin.html#Configuring-Kerberos-with-OpenLDAP-back_002dend


For the 3), I know it is not really related, but if I need to make this ldapadd -Y, I need it to work if I want to add the schema to the olc. And it's not working for me, that's why I want to know if it's mandatory and need to work it out.

Comment: So why is your question entitled 'Need to convert Kerberos.schema?'Your question remains hopelessly confused. There are three separate questions here, and I have answered them all.

Comment: I am sorry, this is not clear rather if I should use olc or not. Ah, I see you get confused, I'll change my title then :)